# Generic Enum Converter for AutoMapper

Tags: c#, enums, automapper

I have the following string to enum converter:

```
    public static T ParseString<T>(string stringValue) where T : struct
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue))
        {
            stringValue = stringValue.Replace(" ", "_");
            T result;

            if (Enum.TryParse<T>(stringValue, out result))
            {
                return result;
            }
        }

        return default(T);
    }
```

Which I am using in a couple of automapper converters:

```
public sealed class StringToGuaranteeTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<string, GuaranteeType>
{
    public GuaranteeType Convert(string source, GuaranteeType destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return EnumExtensions.ParseString<GuaranteeType>(source);
    }
}

public sealed class StringToWhyChooseTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<string, WhyChooseType>
{
    public WhyChooseType Convert(string source, WhyChooseType destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return EnumExtensions.ParseString<WhyChooseType>(source);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to create a generic enum converter for automapper rather than having to create the same thing for each enum I need to convert?

I was hoping for something along the lines of:

```
public sealed class StringToEnumConverter : ITypeConverter<string, T> // this line fails as it does not know what T is here
{
    public T Convert<T>(string source, T destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return EnumExtensions.ParseString<T>(source);
    }
}
```

But my knowledge of how to use `T` is quite limited so obviously this does not work.  Is it even possible with an inherited class?

Comment: I would like to point out, that c# 7.3 finally introduced the Enum type constraint.

Comment: Unfortunately the project is only 6 with no immediate plan to upgrade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

1) You need to include the generic type parameter on the `StringToEnumConverter` class so that it can be passed to the interface definition

2) You need to constrain the generic type since your parser method is constrained

```
public sealed class StringToEnumConverter<T> : ITypeConverter<string, T>
    where T : struct
{
    public T Convert(string source, T destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return EnumExtensions.ParseString<T>(source);
    }
}
```

If you do that, it should work fine:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
                  {
                      cfg.CreateMap<string, GuaranteeType>().ConvertUsing(new StringToEnumConverter<GuaranteeType>());
                      cfg.CreateMap<string, WhyChooseType>().ConvertUsing(new StringToEnumConverter<WhyChooseType>());
                  });

WhyChooseType instance = Mapper.Map<WhyChooseType>("2");
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, saves me a lot of copying and pasting :)

Comment: I'm searching for some similar aproach but converting string => [AnyEnumType] .  I've tried adding the custom ITypeConverter<string, Enum> but property of custom enums are not mathing that definition, only explicit Enum types. Is there some way to link any enum to this  ITypeConverter<string, Enum> implementation ?